# PostgreSQL - select distinct - order by field not returned in select

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, postgresql

We're currently migrating our database back-end from Firebird to PostgreSQL. We use NHibernate as an ORM and the transition has been quite painless albeit a few differences in SQL.

We have one query which we execute using NHibernate.CreateSQLQuery as we build the SQL ourselves. The query returns a string List of the most 5 most recently accessed Ninja names for the passed in UserID.

This was no problem in Firebird using the following SQL;

```
 SELECT FIRST 5 DISTINCT NI.NINJA_NAME
 FROM NINJA_ACCESS NA 
      INNER JOIN NINJAS NI ON NA.NINJA_ID = NI.NINJA_ID
 WHERE NA.USER_ID = 1
 ORDER BY NI.NINJA_ACCESS_DATE DESC
```

Returning an ordered (by access date descending) list of strings.

Now in PostgreSQL we are encountering problems with this simple query;

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ON (NI.NINJA_NAME) NI.NINJA_NAME
 FROM NINJA_ACCESS NA 
      INNER JOIN NINJAS NI ON NA.NINJA_ID = NI.NINJA_ID
 WHERE NA.USER_ID = 1
 ORDER BY NI.NINJA_ACCESS_DATE DESC
 LIMIT 5
```

It appears that we cannot return a single "distinct" column of data with ordering being performed on a separate column that isn't included in the select. Any variation in the above SQL doesn't work unless we include the Access_Date column in the select.

Any ideas how we can resolve this simple query in PostgreSQL?

Side-note: This is an important query for our Ninja Management System, the Ninja's insist that it work!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query should be the equivalent:

```
SELECT n.ninja_name
      ,max(n.ninja_access_date) AS max_access_date
FROM   ninja_access na 
JOIN   ninjas n USING (ninja_id)
WHERE  na.user_id = 1
GROUP  BY n.ninja_name
ORDER  BY 2 DESC
LIMIT  5;
```

- `ORDER BY 2` is just shorthand for `ORDER BY max(n.ninja_access_date)`.
- We need the `max(n.ninja_access_date)` to get the most *recent* entry per `ninja_name`.
  And sort descending to get the most recent names.
- `JOIN   ninjas n USING (ninja_id)` is shorthand for
  `JOIN   ninjas n ON n.ninja_id = na.ninja_id`

You don't have to include the access date in the SELECT list. To only get the names:

```
SELECT n.ninja_name
FROM   ninja_access na 
JOIN   ninjas ni USING (ninja_id)
WHERE  na.user_id = 1
GROUP  BY n.ninja_name
ORDER  BY max(n.ninja_access_date) DESC
LIMIT  5;
```